# I don't know if my dog is trying to kill my kitten or groom it

Tags: cats, dogs, behavior, safety, grooming

I have four dogs and just got a kitten. Three of my dogs just kind of ignore her, but my three-year-old dachshund won't leave her alone. He pins her down and pushes her around with his nose. He licks and nibbles at her. The cat doesn't act like she's distressed, but I'm afraid he might hurt her because he just won't stop.

Comment: male or female dog?

Comment: That cat could really hurt your dachshund. They are friends :-)

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, if the dog wanted to kill the kitten, it would be dead now. This sounds more like playing with the kitten or caring for it in a playful way like a child would care for a doll.

However, your dog should also learn that there are boundaries and that he cannot play with the kitten *all the time*. Since the kitten may not be able to defend herself, you must take on this responsibility. You should tell your dog "no" and separate him from the kitten after a while. Keep standing between your dog and the kitten to tell your dog that he's not allowed to interact with her right now. It will take a while for him to accept that, just like children don't want to stop playing with their toys.

Comment: It's also a good idea to supervise their interactions while the kitten learns to separate herself; even a dog that's so far interacted without injury to the kitten can suddenly change and harm or kill the kitten; until they both learn boundaries, supervision is crucial.